# Regex word boundry \b matches Turkish characters incorrectly

Tags: regex

Here is my regex

> (?i)(\bKH\b)

and it positively matches this Turkish text

> Fıkhî Sorular

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0kRVUO/1)

which is undesirable.

Can someone point me to an explanation of why this is happening and what makes Turkish characters in "Fıkhî" to trigger the match?

And what's a good way to avoid the undesired match?

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using? You might need to add the Unicode flag. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/ROWbEQ/1/) vs [this](https://regex101.com/r/ROWbEQ/2/).

Comment: In PHP, use `u` modifier. In regex101, you just need to select this flag on the right.